# Calculate css path using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, algebra

Given three locations shown in the image below as an example.

[image]

With `x1` being the starting point, `x2` being the mid point, and `x3` being the end point.

`x1` will be any random location along the bottom edge.

`x2` will always be the center of the element.

`x3` will be any random location along the top edge.

The idea is to create a path from `x1` to `x2` then to `x3`, following a path that goes up, then curves at an angle to the left or right(depending on the starting location), then when it gets close to `x2` it curves up towards that point, then following a similar pattern, the same to `x3`.

***Edit for more info***

When the `onwheel` event is trigger, I will determine if it's up or down. Given that information, the element should move from its starting point (`x1`) to the midpoint (`x2`) then to its end point (`x3`) based on the path calculated.

Sorry that I have no code to show for this, I have no idea where to begin on how to calculate a path.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Also, what have you tried to resolve your question? Why did you tag this question with Javascript and CSS without sharing any code?

Comment: Are you talking of animation? Link below may help you: https://css-tricks.com/create-a-responsive-css-motion-path-sure-we-can/

Comment: @PaurushSinha that is something very close to what I am trying to achieve, the path shown in the link is for a fixed path. How would one go about creating a similar path based on 3 given given points?